# How to make javascript date class from string

Tags: javascript

I have api which returns the Date class like this below.

`2022-07-25T12:38:36.443798Z`

Now I want to make the javascript `Date` object from this string.

However Date.parse said to be unstable depending on browser.

So what is the best practice to make `Date` pbject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However Date.parse said to be unstable depending on browser

The spec defines one supported [date time string format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), and all compliant engines must support this format:

> ECMAScript defines a string interchange format for date-times based upon a simplification of the ISO 8601 calendar date extended format. The format is as follows: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ`

Note that this format only specifies sub-second precision to 3-digits, and this is currently the maximum precision of `Date` values in engines.

The same algorithm used by [`Date.parse`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date.parse) is used by the `Date` constructor (`new Date(/*...*/)`) when a [datestring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#datestring) argument is provided, so you can use either to parse the string format you provided and you'll get the same result:

```js
const dateString = '2022-07-25T12:38:36.443798Z';

const date1 = new Date(dateString);
const date2 = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));

console.log('date1 locale:', date1.toLocaleString());
console.log('date2 locale:', date2.toLocaleString());

console.log('date1 UTC:', date1.toISOString());
console.log('date2 UTC:', date2.toISOString());

console.log('date1 ms:', date1.getMilliseconds());
console.log('date2 ms:', date2.getMilliseconds());
```

If you need greater precision than milliseconds, you'll need to use a custom implementation (or wait for [Temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) ).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Date object as follows:

```
new Date("2022-07-25T12:38:36.443798Z");
```

Keep in mind that the browser will use the local machine's timezone. If you need to extract the UTC time use the "getUTC" methods on the date object.

```
.getUTCDate()
.getUTCHours()
```

etc.

Answer (score -1):

Create a date object by calling Date as a constructor:

```js
new Date()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).